# Invalid review question? Can it be removed from the audit queue?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits

[The answer in this review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/305545) looks good enough to me - unless there is a context where this suggestion has been 'answered' so often that it is spam, but that cannot be seen from the audit.

It's not the best of answers, but there is not really much more to say, because the tool does what the OP asks. I have verified on its site that it handles the Word versions that use .docx files (the compatibility pack goes back to 2000, and it's a native format since 2007).

When you look at the [actual question](https://superuser.com/questions/553340/multiple-find-and-replace-in-a-word-document) you see that the answer is no longer there, so obviously I'm supposed to reject the answer in the audit (I tried 'Looks OK' and bingo!)

I suggest removing this question from the audit queue.
(Don't know how to flag/tag it as such)

Comment: Its a known spammer actually.

Comment: OK I'll remember him then. Like the 'Exceltips' guy...

Comment: Part of the process of reviewing questions and answer, you really should check out the actual question, its often very easy to tell if something should be done or if its a test.question.

Comment: @Ramhound Or alternatively, just click to see vote counts (if you have 1k+ rep), as those are based on actual vote count and not displayed vote count.

Comment: I suppose my point was.  Takes more then just looking at whats displayed during the review.