# This audit is ridiculous!

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just hit [this audit in the First Posts review queue](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/680528),
which points to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1232146/150988),
which I’ll quote here in case it gets deleted:

> #### Why is “No scripts” not activated by default in Tor Browser?
>
> I just noticed that the browser extension "No script" is not activated directly after you start the Tor Browser for the first time? This could be a high security risk because it can obviously expose the users IP address and the government can find the whistle blower.
>   [tor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tor)                    asked Jul 21 at 16:10 <sub>by</sub> [Black](https://superuser.com/users/527439/black)

Question body: Two *declarative* sentences (i.e., *statements*),
one of which has a question mark gratuitously appended.

Question *title*: A grammatically sound question
of the form “Why was software *X* designed/coded to do *Y* ?”  
We routinely close questions of this form as primarily opinion-based.

So I clicked on “close”. 
You can guess what happened:

> #### STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention.
>   **You didn't pass.**
>   Your review was inappropriate.
>   This was a high quality post
>   and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.

[image: review audit failure]

(By the way, the vote count on the question is currently +13 / −1.)

The upside is that the question did get [a decent answer](https://superuser.com/q/1232146/150988#1232148). 
But that doesn’t change the fact that it’s a bad question.
Are we really expected to look at ***every*** thing in a review queue
in the “real world”
just to see whether a dozen members of the community liked it?

P.S. In spite of the fact that I’ve complained about this repeatedly,
the audit message *still* says “STOP! Look and Listen.”
even though there is no audio (nothing to listen to).
          :-)          :-(          ?

Comment: Don’t worry; I’m not worried about being review banned.  I have over 14000 reviews on Super User, and this is my first audit failure in a while.

Comment: You might as well close this as a duplicate, e.g., of [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9223/150988), [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9445/150988), [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9008/150988), [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11870/150988), [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9285/150988), or [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8777/150988).   I just wanted to add it to the pantheon of evidence that the review audits are ridiculous.

Comment: *"...review audits are ridiculous"*... **when they don't work as intended.** I've also failed equally ridiculous audits, but *most* of those I failed helpfully educated me. Like with e-mail spam filters, we waste our time complaining about the automated audit system's occasional false positive screw up.

Comment: It's considered a pertinent enough question to be included in the TOR FAQ.

Comment: But, phrased the way it is?  With a declarative sentence with a question mark at the end?  Besides, different sites have different rules.  Maybe they’re OK with opinion-based questions; we aren’t.

Comment: @twisty *most of those I failed helpfully educated me.* You are lucky person.  So far for me its either *We agree that we disagree* or *where is that "I don't understand" button?*

Comment: You would rather _close_ a fairly decent question for sub-optimal use of punctuation than spend the 5 seconds needed to improve it?

Comment: @xenoid I don't believe it to be so much luck as choosing to accept the constructive criticism of a deserved audit failure. Every audit I've failed (that wasn't audit-bot's mistake) has helped me learn how to be a better reviewer.

Comment: The auto-critique was constructive and imo deserved. Hopefully one of these repeated moments can be taken as instructive, if not from the bot, then from these more nuanced human comments. Don't take offense from either. Helping to build (editing & improving) is harder than tearing down (e.g. closing), and requires a human touch & heart.

Comment: Well, as just a user I feel this is like a revenge to those mods who close valid questions so quickly and not paying attention to the details.

Comment: **"STOP! Look and Listen"** is what I was taught to do (in school in the UK) when crossing roads. It essentially meant: "slow down and act carefully before doing something". I think the message is just a spin on that road-crossing tip.

Comment: @MikeChamberlain, I tried editing the post, but you can't just remove the question mark, since you need to change at least six characters, so you get the message: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson, same here. In Canada, it was a little lilting rhyme: Stop, look, and listen // before you cross the street. // Use your eyes, use your ears // before you use your feet. --or something of the sort. Here I'd say we're being cute at the expense of clarity. Whether that's desirable depends on our values.

Comment: @Mathieu K.: Thanks for the rhyme.  As to “our values”: [Stack Exchange hates fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)!

Comment: @AntonKrouglov Most questions are closed by the community not the moderators and the fact you don't know that (or believe otherwise) indicates how more you have to learn.